# Verses that directly or indirectly said Allah is infinite

Tags: allah

What are the Quran verses that directly or indirectly said Allah is infinite in all aspects? I translated the word "infinite" to Arab and I got لانهائي (lianihayiyi), لانهائي, لا نهاية, مطلق (mutlaq) and others and I cannot find the word in Quran.

Comment: "Infinite" is not something we usually use to describe Allah. I suggest researching the attributes of Allah.

Comment: So, it is possible for Allah to be greater than both finite and infinite?

Comment: I think what describes Allah best in the meaning which was known and used by earlier Muslim scholars (not infinite, but maybe something like endless) is the verse:" Say, "If the sea were ink for [writing] the words of my Lord, the sea would be exhausted before the words of my Lord were exhausted, even if We brought the like of it as a supplement."" ([18:109](https://legacy.quran.com/18/109)

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to understand a being whose nature is so apart from what we see and understand. We cannot say if Allah is either exactly infinite or finite.

But we can say that :

1. God can be some way we can't even understand or didn't even think of ;
2. Infinity doesn't exist in the real world, so Allah can potentially be infinite, there isn't something bigger than infinity, there are some infinities bigger than others. Nothing can stop Him from being infinite.
3. Allah is capable to do an infinite amount of things. But we don't know His size, except that He is bigger than anything else that exists.

No one knows the true nature of God. We Muslims only know what God said about Himself in the Three Holy Books (Torah, Bible and Quran), and the sayings of Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him). Anything else we "know" about God is wrong or is an illusion.

There are no verses saying that God is either finite or infinite. Perhaps because infinity as a concept was created centuries later.

*Maybe ask Him in the day of Judgement when you'll be next to Him and hopefully see Him inchaa Allah ;)*

Answer (score 1):

Some say you have to just read quran and just recite it, but let's first agree on that Allah wants us to not only read but think. The phrases of "لعلكم تعقلون" and "لَعَلَّكُمْ تَتَفَكَّرُونَ" meaning "you may use your intellect" and "you might think' repeated many times after some logics are presented in Quran. Allah encouraged us to think about quran verses/signs in various ways [38:29],[47:23],...

Now let's see what we can understand from some Quran Verses:

- [He is the Only True God in the heavens and the earth. He knows whatever you conceal and whatever you reveal, and knows whatever you do.](https://quran.com/6/3)[6:3]
- [The East and the West belong to God. Whichever way you turn, there is the Face of Allah](https://quran.com/2/115)[2:115]
- [{Allah is} The Originator of the heavens and the earth,...There is nothing whatever like Him](https://quran.com/42/11)[42:11]
- [All things perish, except His Face, Judgement is His, and to Him all of you shall return.](https://quran.com/28/88)[28:88]
- [Say: He is Allah, the One and Only;](https://quran.com/112/1)[112:1]. [Allah, the Eternal, Absolute;](https://quran.com/112/2)[112:2]
- [Only God has the knowledge of the coming of the Hour of Doom. He sends down the rain and knows what is in the wombs. No soul is aware of what it will achieve tomorrow and no soul knows in which land it will die. God is All-knowing and All-aware.](https://quran.com/31/34)[31:34]

So Allah is everywhere (in space) but he is not limited to space as He is the Originator and creator of the space (the heavens and the earth). Where was before that? Likewise, he's not limited in time as time is the indefinite continued progress of existence and events inside and between spaces. Allah knows everything from the past, present and future because he is present and he isn't bound in time.

Allah is the greater (Allah o Akbar). We all heard this phrase, and Quran says "Glory to Allah! (He is free) from the things they ascribe (to Him)! [37:180]" and Prophet Muhammad's grandson (Peace Be Upon Them) who’s one of the greatest Islamic scholars, in response to someone who said Allah o Akbar means God is greater THAN EVERYTHING, explained that it means ["God is greater TO BE DESCRIBED."](https://shiaonlinelibrary-com.translate.goog/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A8/2436_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D9%85%D8%AB%D9%84-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%AA%D9%81%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%B1-%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%86%D8%B2%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B4%D9%8A%D8%AE-%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%B5%D8%B1-%D9%85%D9%83%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%85-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B4%D9%8A%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B2%D9%8A-%D8%AC-%D9%A9/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D8%A9_180?_x_tr_sch=http&_x_tr_sl=ar&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=sc#:%7E:text=God%20is%20too%20great%20to%20be%20described.%E2%80%9D%20(1)) thus God is not like anything to be compared.

So God should not be a body of finite matter in space. The imagination of Allah is impossible as "He is not like anything[42:11]". He is absolute [112:2] and infinite, meaning there is nothing but Allah and at the same time every existence is in His presence but not as independent beings beside or inside Allah that their existence has limited Allah. This is impossible for us to understand as "Except for a little knowledge you have been given nothing[17:85]".
I fear Allah and I hope he guides us all to the right path of understanding while we think. Jesus (Peace Be Upon Him) to Allah: “You know what is in my soul, but I do not know what is in Yours. It is You who has absolute knowledge of the unseen.[5:116]

What I'm certain is that Allah is the perfect.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no time or space, number or measurements that Allah is bound to so technically or logically speaking he must be infinite. Everything that’s created is also or has to be within this infinite god. There can also only be one infinite hence allah is one. If allah was limited to a particular size then we would have to come up with the answer to why he is limited and who limited him to that size. The only logical explanation that makes perfect sense is that Allah is infinite in everything & eternal. There are also no doubts raised with these traits.